# Given a (2,1) category is there a canonical way of constructing a 1-category?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Given a (2,1)-category (for example, the category of algebraic stacks over some fixed site), you can consider the 1-category with the same objects, but where morphisms between the objects are just 2-isomorphism classes of morphisms in the original (2,1)-category.

Does this construction make sense?

Is there anything that one has to be careful of? (perhaps one needs to restrict to suitably nice algebraic stacks?)

Does anyone have a reference for this construction?

Comment: Isn't this just the notion of the "homotopy category" of your (2,1)-category? I don't know anything about stacks, but the classic example of what you're doing here is taking the (2,1)-category of topological spaces (whose 2-morphisms are homotopies) and identifying homotopic continuous maps. I think this makes sense in all higher categories, and there is a canonical "quotient functor" from a (higher) category to its homotopy category. Someone more in the know may correct me on this though.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the homotopy category of the original 2-category. It's just given by applying $\pi_0$ to each hom-groupoid.

Comment: In general, if $F : V \to V'$ is a monoidal functor, it induces a functor from $V$-enriched categories to $V'$-enriched categories given by applying $F$ to hom-objects. This doesn't quite settle the issue here because $(2, 1)$-categories are not quite categories enriched in groupoids, but the subtleties are invisible after passing to $\pi_0$.